# Как передать несколько json списков в Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Никак не могу понять как отправить 2 JSON объекта в представление?

Имеется метод который принимает данные с помощью AJAX и выполняет фильтрацию. Потом добавляет отфильтрованные объекты в словарь `ctx`, потом конвертирует словарь в JSON и возвращает его в представление.  Однако Django мне с пеной у рта говорит, что `stations` представляет собой объект QuerySet поэтому его нельзя сериализовать с помощью `json.dumps()` об этом говорит ошибка `Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`. Если выполнить сериализацию с помощью `serializers.serialize()` появиться другая ошибка '`str' object has no attribute '_meta'`. Получается каждый JSON объект надо сериализовать по разному. Возникает проблема как тогда их передать в представление?

**views.py:**

```
def filter(request):
    if request.GET:
        filter = request.GET.get('filter')
        decoded_filter = json.loads(filter)  # из строки инициализирует объект
        stations = Station.objects.all()
        id_net = Net.objects.filter(name=decoded_filter["net"])
        list_id_stations = Networkstations.objects.filter(idnet__in=id_net).values_list("idstation", flat=True)
        list_name_net = []
        if decoded_filter["net"] != 'all':
            stations = stations.filter(id__in=list_id_stations)
        if decoded_filter["type"] != 'all':
            stations = stations.filter(type=decoded_filter["type"])
        for station in stations:
            list_name_net.append(
                list(Networkstations.objects.filter(idstation=station.id).values('idnet__name')))
        ctx = {
            'stations': stations,
            'list_name_net': list_name_net,
        }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Попробуйте возвращать через JsonResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: @super16 Пробовал, всё равно появляются те же ошибки

Comment: @super16 Может быть существует способ создать 3-ю модель, которая будет содержать внутри себя поля модели Station, а также список list_name_net, а потом обращаться к ней как к обычной модели? Тогда и с сериализацией проблем может не будет? Проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю как это сделать?

Comment: Лучше тогда сериализовать query-объекты с методом fields, а не values, и ещё я бы попробовал делать json.dumps не с query-объектами, а со списками (то есть не оборачивать всё в переменную ctx, а конвертировать в list)